# Debian sid freezing randomly

Tags: debian, kde, freeze

My Debian Sid (KDE) OS (on a PC with an Nvidia GTX 970, proprietary drivers, an i7-8700K CPU, and 16GB RAM) has begun freezing randomly.  Once or twice a day, it's completely unresponsive; the mouse won't move, and SysRq does nothing.

This began after upgrading a bunch of packages. I checked syslog but nothing sticks out at me. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong, or advice on how I can debug the issue?

```
/var/log/messsages

May 16 10:33:20 hiiaka kernel: [17020.784351] perf: interrupt took too long (2503 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
May 16 12:03:17 hiiaka kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xaa, date = 2018-12-12
May 16 12:03:17 hiiaka kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-2)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.28-2 (2019-03-15)                                                  
May 16 12:03:17 hiiaka kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.19.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/hiiaka--vg-root ro quiet
```

List of recent package history is here: https://pastebin.com/eZH1qf2e

Comment: @K7AAY I don't think there are any messages in there during that time, 12:03:17 is when I rebooted after the freeze. I added that part of the file in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested - I tried several things:

- bios update
- memtest came up clean
- switch to Cinnamon
- downgrading nvidia drivers to previous version
- setting intel_idle.max_cstate

and some other less notable things. Eventually I compiled a newer version of the kernel and have had no freezes for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

**nvidia** sucks. Use stock-drivers instead of the NVidia ones.

[More details about NVidia and Linus here](https://linux.slashdot.org/story/12/06/20/1237257/nvidia-responds-to-linus-torvalds)